# Blender's render calculation takes too much time without CPU/GPU usage. How to fix?

Tags: blender

When I render animation in Blender, on each frame Blender starts calculations and I can see: "Render: 0%" for 5 mins for each frame and at the same time Blender doesn't use CPU/GPU at this moment (CPU load from Blender 5%, GPU 0%) After calculations (5 min) my GPU works as should and render frame in few seconds. So for each frame I have to wait about 5 min to render it in few seconds. Is there a way to solve this problem? I use OptiX and 3080Ti to render, Cycles, other settings all default, simple scene with liquid.

Tried to google and found solutions only for speed up rendering process which I don't have problems with, problem with calculations before actual render couldn't find on google

Comment: I also noticed that Blender is not at all being efficient in the way it uses system resources. I'd expect parallelization, back-to-back renders, keeping GPU fully utilized the entire time. I wonder if 3rd party renderers are more efficient.